# Локализация программы (С++, WinAPI)

Tags: winapi, локализация, c++

Пару раз приходилось создавать локализацию под Windows Mobile. Там все просто: создал DLL-ку с именем программы и расширением *.0419.MUI, записывал в нее необходимые строковые ресурсы, прописал в коде и далее операционная система автоматически подгружает нужный язык при запуске программы в зависимости от языка выбранного в системе.
Сейчас столкнулся с необходимостью локализовать программу для настольного ПК. Программа написана в Visual Studio 2005 на C++ (WinAPI). И, собственно, никак не могу найти информацию, работает такой метод здесь или нет? Если нет, то как реализовывается локализация в этой версии Windows? Ткните носом, пожалуйста.

Comment: Для локализации было предусмотрено размещение строк в ресурсах exe/dll. Правда для замены строк при этом требуется корректировка или пересборка этих самых exe/dll

Comment: А подгрузка происходит также автоматически?

Comment: LoadString() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx 

Да, ещё. Для .net гугл подсказывает 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d17ax2xk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

Comment: Я имею ввиду подгрузку библиотеки. Поясню: я теста ради попробовал реализовать по той же схеме, что описал в вопросе. Программа не видит MUI-файла. Нужно сделать что-то еще кроме указанных действий или настольная Windows не поддерживает такой метод?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Настольная система ничего не делает за тебя, если только manifest иногда для контролов генерит. Здесь делаешь так, все ресурсы хранишь в DLL, далее грузишь в своё приложение функцией LoadLibrary данную DLL-ку.
HMODULE module = LoadLibrary("res.dll");
Далее module он же(HINSTANCE) используй везде куда просят. LoadIcon/LoadCursor, LoadBitmap/LoadImage.

Comment: Действительно то, что нужно. Спасибо! А как узнать код языка системы? С помощью GetUserDefaultLCID() или лучше как-то иначе?